# Parcel Build throws the error [Error: Error opening directory]

Tags: javascript, parcel

I'm new at parcel and node packages and I'm tryng do deploy my projet to github pages using Parcel ad gh-pages. I created the following scrip at `package.json`

`"build:parcel": "parcel build ./src/index.html"`

the problem is when it finish building, throws the error [Error: Error opening directory]

```
✨ Built in 327ms

dist\index.html              3.04 KB    3.02s
dist\index.955ccd1a.css    183.28 KB    103ms
dist\index.3e71ab34.js       2.26 KB    190ms
dist\index.607dc078.js     173.57 KB    2.25s
[Error: Error opening directory]
```

sometimes, even when I run the script `"start": "parcel ./src/index.html"` parcel do not create the dist folder.

My full `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "herosacai",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://venifeitosa.github.io/herosacai/",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel ./src/index.html",
    "build:parcel": "parcel build ./src/index.html",
    "clear:wind": "rd /s/q dist",
    "build": "npm run clear:wind && npm run build:parcel",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just sometimes ? Maybe a parcel  cache problem...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem adding the parameter `--no-cache` at the parcel scripts

before:

```
"start": "parcel ./src/index.html"

"build:parcel": "parcel build ./src/index.html"
```

after:

```
"start": "parcel ./src/index.html --no-cache"

"build:parcel": "parcel build ./src/index.html --no-cache"
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear parcel cache and continue as before.

```
rm -rf .parcel-cache
```